# select subquery inside then of case when statement? or how to do otherwise?

Tags: sql, database, scalar-subquery

it's just an example. (My point is how can I do when I'm getting more then one result in the CASE statement):

```
SELECT 
,@PARAM AS id 
,Date=( 
SELECT distinct CASE
    WHEN P.DATE1 <= 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
    THEN 'X'
    WHEN P.DATE1 > 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
    THEN 'Y
    WHEN P.DATE2 > 10
    THEN 'Z' 
 END )
 FROM Prod AS P
```

The error is as follows:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression**

Comment: There is no "subquery" in your example

Comment: You only have 1 query in your question, where/what is the subquery. You need to provide more context if you want anyone to try and help you.

Comment: If you give an example and/or explain words what you want then we might know what you *want* your query to be.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is returning several rows. You need to modity it to returning a single row, with a single column, either by filtering, or by adding a TOP 1 to it. For example:

```
,Date=( 
SELECT distinct CASE
  WHEN P.DATE1 <= 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
  THEN 'X'
  WHEN P.DATE1 > 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
  THEN 'Y
  WHEN P.DATE2 > 10
  THEN 'Z' 
END 
WHERE -- >> your filter here <<
)
```

or

```
,Date=( 
SELECT TOP 1 distinct CASE
  WHEN P.DATE1 <= 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
  THEN 'X'
  WHEN P.DATE1 > 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
  THEN 'Y
  WHEN P.DATE2 > 10
  THEN 'Z' 
END )
```

The case when is only defining what value to retunr in each row, not replacing a number of rows with a single value.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want a subselect/subquery, you proabably just want a case:

```
SELECT 
,@PARAM AS id 
,(CASE
    WHEN P.DATE1 <= 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
    THEN 'X'
    WHEN P.DATE1 > 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
    THEN 'Y
    WHEN P.DATE2 > 10
    THEN 'Z' 
 END) AS Date
 FROM Prod AS P
```

Your error was because `Date = (SELECT ...)` does a query (per row of P) and must have exactly one column and row returned to be set to Date.

Answer (score 0):

Currently wouldn't work if date was 10 as it would have matched all three of your conditions, you need to remove the `=` on your `<` and `>`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
                WHEN Date < 10 
                THEN 'X'
                WHEN Date = 10 
                THEN 'Y'
                WHEN Date > 10 
                THEN 'Z'
                END
```

Comment: It would work, just that it would always evaluate to `X` for the value *10* (See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42851)).

Comment: SQL Server short-circuits `case` statements, so the first matching expression will be selected

Comment: That means the query essentially wouldn't work as it wouldn't return the required value for 10, which is `Y`

Comment: this is the error that the query generate : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=  or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @BIProgrammer The subquery you are talking about is missing from the question. Update the question with the correct query.

Comment: @BIProgrammer you need to include all of your code in your question

Comment: @Matt Your answer is not related to the question. Your answer solves another "problem" that the OP might or might not have (if he considers it important).

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu *Not a mind reader* can only answer what is shown in the question

Comment: @Matt True, but the query he posted is not related to what the text of the question is: *"that returns more then 1 result"*. Anyway, the OP can take note of your answer, but I don't think he even knows he has this "problem" you're fixing for him.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I went with the assumption that it meant *returns wrong result* i.e. returing X instead of Y when date is 10. Yeah lets see what the update brings :) ....

Comment: its just an example (My point is how can I do when i'm getting more then 1result in the Case statement):                  SELECT 
,@PARAM AS id
,Date = (
 SELECT distinct
  CASE WHEN P.DATE1 <= 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
   THEN 'X'
   WHEN P.DATE1 > 05 and P.DATE2 <= 10
   THEN 'Y'
   WHEN P.DATE2 > 10
   THEN 'Z'
  END
)
FROM Prod AS P                                                                                         the error is as follow : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=  or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @BIProgrammer Please edit a comment like this into your question (but we did it for you).